# How to add a smoother on the facets in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new to ggplot2. Is it possible to add a smoother only to data, for which there is a signficant correlation at a level of 0.05?

I tried using the following code to extract data of significant correlations, and then add a smoother to the subset. But it didn't work.

```
my_custom_df <- function(p) {
  function(df) {
    fit <- lm(y ~ x, data = df)
    fs <- summary(fit)$fstatistic
    pValue <- pf(fs[1], fs[2], fs[3], lower.tail = FALSE)

      if (pValue < p) {
        df
       }
    }
}

dat.sig <- ddply(dat, 'g', my_custom_df(0.05))

gp <- ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = c, y = v)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(data = dat.sig, method = 'lm') + facet_wrap( ~ g, scales = 'free', ncol = 2)
```

Expected result

[image]

my data:

```
c = rep(c(3,2,1.5,1.25,1,0.65),4)
g = c(rep('narG',6), rep('napA',6), rep('nirK',6), rep('nirS',6))
v = c(0.5, 8.0, 19.1, 34.8, 60.6, 63.5, 1.5, 0, 3.7, 22.4, 4.7, 7.9, 2780.7, 179.2, 327.6, 2213, 370.6, 151.4, 13.6, 0.7, 0.1, 1846.9, 132.4, 79)*100000
```

Comment: Your code work, you just need to replace `fit <- lm(y ~ x, data = df)` with `fit <- lm(v ~ c, data = df)`. Then the definition of `dat` is missing but I imagine is just `data.frame(c,g,v)`

Comment: `@adiana`, I am sorry for forgetting to present  `dat = data.frame(c,g,v)`. I am not sure about the function. When I get a new df, I have to enter new names for `x` and `y` in `fit <- lm(y ~ x, data = df)`.  Could it be made universal? as i want to just enter the 'p'.

Comment: How can the algorithm understand who `x` and `y` are?

Comment: `@adiana`, thank you for your comments. I have another question if you dont mind. Is there any way to control the heights of the strip text background? I tried using

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge, what is the strip text background?

Comment: I tried using `g <- ggplotGrob()` `g$heights[[3]] = unit(2, 'in')` `grid.draw(g)`, but it didn't work.

Comment: `@adiana`, Sorry, I mean the deep color stripes behind `narG`, `napA`, ...in the plot.

Comment: You don't like the grey or the font?